# How to extract the longest match?

Tags: r, regex, stringr, purrr

Consider this simple example

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

dataframe <- data_frame(text = c('how is the biggest ??',
                                 'really amazing stuff'))

# A tibble: 2 x 1
  text                 
  <chr>                
1 how is the biggest ??
2 really amazing stuff
```

I need to extract some terms based on a `regex` expression, **but only extract the term that is the longest**.

So far, I was able to only extract the first match (not necessary the longest) using `str_extract`.

```
> dataframe %>% mutate(mymatch = str_extract(text, regex('\\w+')))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  text                  mymatch
  <chr>                 <chr>  
1 how is the biggest ?? how    
2 really amazing stuff  really
```

I tried to play with `str_extract_all` but I cant find an efficient syntax.
Output should be:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  text                  mymatch
  <chr>                 <chr>  
1 how is the biggest ?? biggest
2 really amazing stuff  amazing
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

dataframe %>%
  mutate(mymatch = sapply(str_extract_all(text, '\\w+'), 
                          function(x) x[nchar(x) == max(nchar(x))][1]))
```

With `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

dataframe %>%
  mutate(mymatch = map_chr(str_extract_all(text, '\\w+'), 
                           ~ .[nchar(.) == max(nchar(.))][1]))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
                   text mymatch
                  <chr>   <chr>
1 how is the biggest ?? biggest
2  really amazing stuff amazing
```

**Note:**

If there is a tie, this takes the first one.

**Data:**

```
dataframe <- data_frame(text = c('how is the biggest ??',
                                 'really amazing biggest stuff'))
```

Comment: really cool. can you possibly use `purrr` instead of `sapply`?

Comment: really cool! perhaps just one quirk. assume two matches have the same lenght, how to return just, say, the first one?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Easy, just add `[1]` to extract the first one from `.[nchar(.) == max(nchar(.))]`

Comment: Not sure why this answer got downvoted. It would be nice if the downvoter could write a comment explaining the vote so I can improve my answer.

Comment: as said below, I think some weirdo troll had fun with us.. anyway, great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to break the process down into 2 steps, first a list of list of all the words in each row.  Then find and return the longest word from each sub list:

```
df <- data_frame(text = c('how is the biggest ??',
                                 'really amazing stuff'))

library(stringr)
#create a list of all words per row
splits<-str_extract_all(df$text, '\\w+', simplify = FALSE)
#find longest word and return it
sapply(splits, function(x) {x[which.max(nchar(x))]})
```

Answer (score 2):

As a variant of other answers, I'd suggest writing a function that does the manipuation

```
longest_match <- function(x, pattern) {
    matches <- str_match_all(x, pattern)
    purrr::map_chr(matches, ~ .[which.max(nchar(.))])
}
```

Then use it

```
dataframe %>%
    mutate(mymatch = longest_match(text, "\\w+"))
```

By way of commentary, it seems better practice to isolate the function that does the new stuff `longest_match()` from the manipulations enabled by `mutate()`. For instance, the function is easy to test, can be used in other circumstances, and can be modified ('return the last rather than first longest match') independently of the data transformation step.. There's no real value in sticking everything into one line, so it makes sense to write lines of code that logically accomplish one thing -- find all matches, map from all matches to longest, ... `purrr::map_chr()` is better than `sapply()` because it is more robust -- it guarantees that the result is a character vector, so that something like

```
> df1 = dataframe[FALSE,]
> df1 %>% mutate(mymatch = longest_match(text, "\\w+"))
# A tibble: 0 x 2
# ... with 2 variables: text <chr>, mymatch <chr>
```

'does the right thing', i.e., `mymatch` is a character vector (`sapply()` would return a list in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Or, using `purrr`...

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

dataframe %>% mutate(mymatch=map_chr(str_extract_all(text,"\\w+"),
                                     ~.[which.max(nchar(.))]))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  text                  mymatch
  <chr>                 <chr>  
1 how is the biggest ?? biggest
2 really amazing stuff  amazing
```